# mutating data frame with search by row in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I created this data frame as an illustration of a larger problem.

```
> df <- data.frame(x=c(NA, 12, NA, 67), y=c(32, NA, NA, NA), z=c(NA, NA, NA, NA))
> df
   x  y  z
1 NA 32 NA
2 12 NA NA
3 NA NA NA
4 67 NA NA
```

I want it to look like this.

```
   x
1 32
2 12
3 NA
4 67
```

Which is essentially searching through each row for a number. If one is found to return it matching that row, and if no number is found, return an NA.

I created an empty vector.

```
> list <- c()
```

Then a for loop that goes through each row returning the element that is not an NA value. Then add it to the 'list' vector.

```
> for (i in 1:4) {list <- c(list, df[i,!is.na(df[i,])])}
> list
[[1]]
[1] 32

[[2]]
[1] 12

[[3]]
[1] 67

> unlist(list)

32 12 67
```

This gets close, but the NA rows are ignored.

I also tried a grep pattern match. But as you can imagine, the grep family of calls are designed to run through vectors and not data frame rows.

Not sure how to move forward. Again, if it could look like:

```
   x
1 32
2 12
3 NA
4 67
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apply` to check for values in each row:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) { z <- x[!is.na(x)]; if(length(z)) z else NA})
# [1] 32 12 NA 67
```

Another strategy is to use `rowSums`, but this solution only works if there are no `0` values in your data.frame (if there are, this method will replace those results with `NA`):

```
x <- rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE); x[x == 0] <- NA; x
# [1] 32 12 NA 67
```

Comment: Perfect! And the first function is robust enough to handle character elements too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Reduce` function to combine columns pair by pair:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) {x[!is.na(y)] <- y[!is.na(y)] ; x}, df)
# [1] 32 12 NA 67
```

This function should work with non-numeric data, handles rows with multiple non-NA elements gracefully (it takes the rightmost), and should be a good deal more efficient than one relying on `apply`.

```
df.big <- df[rep(1:4, 1000),]
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(apply(df.big, 1, function(x) { z <- x[!is.na(x)]; if(length(z)) z else NA}), {x <- rowSums(df.big, na.rm = TRUE); x[x == 0] <- NA; x}, Reduce(function(x, y) {x[!is.na(y)] <- y[!is.na(y)] ; x}, df.big))
# Unit: microseconds
#                                                                                               expr       min
#  apply(df.big, 1, function(x) {     z <- x[!is.na(x)]     if (length(z))          z     else NA }) 14550.050
#                               {     x <- rowSums(df.big, na.rm = TRUE)     x[x == 0] <- NA     x }   239.826
#                          Reduce(function(x, y) {     x[!is.na(y)] <- y[!is.na(y)]     x }, df.big)   353.326
#          lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
#  15322.4825 19124.8814 17008.2935 22037.387 43337.893   100
#    257.2215   389.4275   380.6595   424.593  1585.234   100
#    384.4750   457.9714   436.2400   511.085   799.992   100
```

Basically the approach is about as efficient as the `rowSums` one proposed by @Thomas but can handle character and other data.